# "No valid checkpoint found" when restoring xtrabackup

Tags: galera, backup, mariadb-10.1, xtrabackup

I have a cluster of MariaDB 10.1 servers, master/master with one node acting as arbitrator and incremental backups with xtrabackup.

This is how I've pieced it together from the docs.

Master01 does a base backup once using this command:

```
innobackupex --defaults-file="/etc/xtrabackup_client/backup.cnf" \
  --socket="..." --extra-lsndir="/etc/xtrabackup_client/" \
  --stream=xbstream /tmp | \
  ssh "$backup_username@$backup_server"  "cat - | xbstream -x -C /var/backups/xtrabackup/"
```

After that I do incremental backups every day with this command:

```
innobackupex --defaults-file="$mysql_defaults_file" \
  --socket="..." --extra-lsndir="/etc/xtrabackup_client" --stream=xbstream \
  --incremental --incremental-lsn="$to_lsn" /tmp | \
  ssh "$backup_username@$backup_server" "cat - | xbstream -x -C /var/backups/xtrabackup_incremental/"
```

/etc/xtrabackup_client/backup.cnf looks like this.

```
[client]
user=backup
password=secret
```

This is done in scripts, hence the variables here and there. (I've also removed some to hopefully clarify.)

This seems to work, I get a base backup and I get incremental backups created.

The problem happens when I try to do a restore test.

**For restoring I follow this procedure on the arbitrator-node.**

First I run a script that loops through the base backup and all the incremental backups in rising chronological order and verifies the LSN.

I've pasted the script in [gist here](https://gist.github.com/stemid/beb1b593b737b5ee92891077ca696b00#file-xtrabackup_prepare-sh).

If all looks good I run another script to merge the incremental backups, [gist here](https://gist.github.com/stemid/beb1b593b737b5ee92891077ca696b00#file-xtrabackup_merge-sh).

This results in one base backup that by size looks the same as the live copy on the master servers.

I then want to test it so I do `innobackupex --copy-back /var/backups/xtrabackup` which copies the base backup into /var/db/mysql which is the datadir configured in /etc/mysql.

That server does not have a mysqld binary installed so I rsync the whole dir over to a restore server with the same MariaDB 10.1 version as the master servers.

Then I try to run it as root with this command:

```
sudo -u mysql /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr \
  --datadir=/var/db/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin \
  --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid \
  --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
```

But I get this output:

```
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.20-MariaDB-1~trusty) starting as process 24455 ...
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] Using unique option prefix 'myisam_recover' is error-prone and can break in the future. Please use the full name 'myisam-recover-options' instead.
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 256.0M
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found.
InnoDB: If you are attempting downgrade from MySQL 5.7.9 or later,
InnoDB: please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-downgrading.html
InnoDB: If this error appears when you are creating an InnoDB database,
InnoDB: the problem may be that during an earlier attempt you managed
InnoDB: to create the InnoDB data files, but log file creation failed.
InnoDB: If that is the case, please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-creating-innodb.html
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2017-01-03 18:55:41 140551642929088 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Which makes little sense to me so I'm here asking for help.

Comment: What happens if you restore with flag `--myisam-recover-options=off`

Comment: Actually, in reviewing the logs more closely ... why is this appearing? `Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB`? Did you install/configure InnoDB on that server?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/379714/unknown-unsupported-storage-engine-innodb-mysql-ubuntu

Comment: @jcolebrand You're pointing in the right direction. I tried starting with default-storage-engine=innodb and it would start but trying to access any of the restored DBs I get "Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'" so I'll have to look up if my current storage engine is innodb or xtradb. I tried starting with default-storage-engine=xtradb but couldn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jcolebrand and some more googling helped steer me in the right direction on this one.

InnoDB engine is failing to start. So Show engines showed InnoDB as not supported if I started with myisam as default engine.

[This github issue](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/93#issuecomment-227405418) hinted that a few old logfiles had to be removed.

Specifically I removed the following files but the number of ib_logfile files depends on your system.

- aria_log_control
- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1

Move them to another dir and try starting the service again. This worked for me.